# two submit on 1 Formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

this is my code:

```
<Formik
      initialValues={{
        email: 'eve.holt@reqres.in',
        password: '',
      }}
      validationSchema={TodoInputSchema}
      onSubmit={values => {
        // handleToggle
        // handleTodoInputSubmit
      }}>
      {({values, handleChange, handleSubmit, touched, errors}) => (
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text
              style={[
                styles.completeAll,
                todos.every(({complete}) => complete) &&
                  styles.completeFilterColor,
              ]}>
              {String.fromCharCode(10003)}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TextInput
            editable={!loading}
            returnKeyType="done"
            onSubmitEditing={handleAddTodo}
            blurOnSubmit={false}
            placeholder="What needs to be done?"
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={newText => setNewTodoText(newText)}
            value={newTodoText}
          />
          )}
        </View>
      )}
    </Formik>
```

as you can see i have toggle and Input. I am just wondering if it's possible to do maybe 2 submits on toggle and input for 1 Formik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Your code for submit will be like:

```
onSubmit={(values) => {
     handleToggle();
     return handleTodoInputSubmit(values);
}}>
```

And [there](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik) shown example from docs.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my approach: on Initial values I have a variable ButtonAction initialized with a default action - then on my buttons I update the value before submitting the form.

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {
    setFieldValue("ButtonAction", "SUBMIT_TXN", false);
    handleSubmit();
  }}
  variant="secondary"
  disabled={!(isValid && dirty) || isSubmitting}
>
  Submit
</Button>
<Button
  variant="primary"
  onClick={() => {
    setFieldValue("ButtonAction", "COMPLETE_TXN", false);
    handleSubmit();
  }}
  disabled={!(isValid && dirty) || isSubmitting}
>
  Complete
</Button>
```

then on my onSubmit method I check the value of my ButtonAction and act accordingly.